# How can I use both Super and Super+L as different keyboard shortcuts in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, archlinux, xfce

Using `xfce4-keyboard-settings`, I have `SuperL` keybound to start rofi using `rofi -show drun`, but this prevents me from using `SuperL` in combination with any other key combinations, such as `Super + L` to lock the screen. `rofi` is hijacking the show immediately.

I've tried prepending a sleep to `rofi`, ie. `sh -c "sleep 1 && rofi -show drun"`, which correctly sleeps and even lets me use `Super + L` to lock the screen, but then `rofi` loads over the top and starts to interact weirdly (read: undesirably) with the lock screen.

Is there a way that I can have both keyboard shortcuts work as desired without interfering with eachother?

BTW, the lock screen I'm using is i3lock-fancy.

Comment: You should use xcape to overcome this limitation. [More details](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7845#c57).

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. I may be doing it incorrectly. I installed xcape and added xcape -e 'Super_L=Control_L|Escape' to ~/.xinitrc, then bound Ctrl+Esc to rofi -show drun, and Super+L to i3lock-fancy. After reboot, Super opens rofi correctly, but Super+L does not run i3lock-fancy. It triggers something else that moves & resizes the current window somewhat arbitrarily. What am I missing?

Comment: Check in Window Manager -> Keyboard if Super+L is assigned to any action.

Comment: Yep, it was. I removed another default assignment for Super+L in obkey. I also had to put the xcape -e command in ~/.config/openbox/autostart rather than xinitrc for it to work on each boot. It's all working perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this following AndreLDM's advice.

I installed xcape, and added `xcape -e 'Super_L=Control_L|Escape'` to `~/.config/openbox/autostart` and bound the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Esc to run rofi. I was then able to keybind Super+L to i3lock-fancy and have both keyboard shortcuts work as I intended. Pressing Super by itself presents my rofi drun menu, and Super+L locks the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I was after the exact same functionality on Manjaro XFCE. I found that even though the whisker menu popup was bound to <Alt + F1>, it still popped up when I pressed < SuperL >. So instead of binding rofi to  I bound it to <Alt + F1>.
With that I was able to start rofi with < SuperL > and also use it in combination with other keys.

You may need to install [this package](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey).

> ksuperkey allows you to open the application launcher in desktop
> environments such as KDE Plasma and Xfce using the Super key (also
> known as "Meta" or "the Windows key"). If you hold down the Super key
> it will still act as a modifier key, allowing you to use it for other
> keyboard shortcuts.